# need to update the ngModel value on angular-ui bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

In NG-UI bootstrap calendar, i am able to view the date format correctly but the value inside the ngmodel seems to be date string like Wed Oct 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT).

I tried to update my ngmodel to hold the value 10/18/2017. But i am facing $apply already in progress errors.

```
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="screeningDateFromSearch" 
       datepicker-popup uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
       placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
       ng-model="searchInput.screeningDateFrom"
       is-open="datesPicker.screeningDateFrom"
       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
       show-button-bar="false" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"
       ng-change="searchScreenings()" />
```

```
angular.module('moduleName')
    .directive('datepickerPopup', function (dateFilter) {
        return {
            require: '^ngModel',
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                var dateFormat = attrs.uibDatepickerPopup;
                attrs.$observe('datepickerPopup', function (newValue) {
                    if (dateFormat == newValue || !ctrl.$modelValue) return;
                    dateFormat = newValue;
                    ctrl.$modelValue = new Date(ctrl.$setViewValue);
                });

                ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                    if (!dateFormat || !modelValue) return "";
                    var retVal = dateFilter(modelValue).format(dateFormat);
                    return retVal;
                });

                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    var date = dateFilter(viewValue, dateFormat);
                    scope.$apply(function (viewValue) {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        ctrl.$render();
                    });
                });

            }
        };
    })
```

Later tried with $scope.safeApply, but that too doesn't work on this code snippet
Please suggest the best way to update the value.

Comment: The [$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) method automaically invokes a digest cycle. Why do you feel you need to use `$apply`?

Comment: With the [uib-datepicker-popup directve](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup), the `ng-model` should be set to a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) not a string. Your `datepicker-popup` directive is fighting the `uib-datepicker-popup` directive. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I am trying to update the overwrite the ng-model  value to 10/18/2017.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `ng-change`

```
$scope.searchScreenings = function(){
    var screeningDateFrom =  $filter('date')($scope.searchInput.screeningDateFrom, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$filter` in your controller